# Vector or a real number? Derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

For a manifold $M$ and a path $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to M$
what type of object is this:

$\dot{\alpha}(t)$

?

**Is it a vector or a real number?**

In the same way, for a function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ what is this

$\dot{\alpha}(f)$

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dot{\alpha}(t)$ is a tangent vector. $\dot{\alpha}(f)$ is a real number (when evaluated at some value of $t$), which can also be notated $\frac{d}{dt}f(\alpha(t)).$